# how can i fix mysql error with cronjob (node-cron)

Tags: mysql, node.js, idempotent, node-cron

Am using node-cron to run a cron job every 12 Oclock Midnight, the job am running is to increment some data on the user table,
the issue now is that the job will run twice.

e.g I wanna increment 15, after 12 o'clock, it will turn to 17 instead of 16.

have tried my possible best to detect the issue, am unable.

When I stop the Nodejs Application, the MySQL database keeps updating, whereas have already off the nodejs application
here is the job am running

```js
const CronJob = require('cron').CronJob;
const logger = require("../helpers/logger");
const { updateUser } = require("../helpers/user");
const db = require("../models/db");



const job = new CronJob('* * * * *', async function() {
    
    db.query("UPDATE sponsored_posts SET post_status = 0", (err, data) => {
        if (err) logger.debug(err)
    });

    db.query("DELETE FROM sponsored_posts", (err, data) => {
        if (err) logger.debug(err)
    });


    //EXPIRING USER
    db.query("SELECT * FROM all_users WHERE membership_expired > 0", async (err, data) => {
        if (data.length > 0) {
            //FIlter Through All User
            //Deduct While They Havent Expired
            await data.map(async user => {
                await updateUser({
                        uid: parseInt(user.uid),
                        membership_expired: user.membership_expired - 1
                })
                
            })
        }
    })
    
    db.query("SELECT * FROM all_users WHERE membership_expired = 0", async (err, data) => {
        if (data.length > 0) {
            //FIlter Through All User
            //Set Can Purchase To 1
            await data.map(async user => {
                await updateUser({
                    uid: parseInt(user.uid),
                    can_purchase: 1
                })
                
            })
        }
    });

    
    
    
}, null, false, "Africa/Lagos");

job.start();
```

Comment: Can you please [edit] your question to show the code where you invoke node-cron?

Comment: have edited it,

Comment: Your cron pattern is `* * * * *`. But [node-cron](https://www.npmjs.com/package/cron#available-cron-patterns) takes six items, not five. And, a six-star cron pattern means "run this job every second". To run the job [daily at midnight](https://github.com/kelektiv/node-cron/blob/master/examples/at_midnight.js) you need `0 0 0 * * *`. And, your code doesn't have any SQL UPDATE statements in it. It seems likely your unwanted UPDATE is somewhere else in your code.

Answer (score 0):

If you are using a Linux system you can use the crontab command to set your cronJob

1. Create a sh file

> example, your-cron.sh
> // write your cron script execution commend there
> node youscript.js
> //or
> npm run yourscript
>
> make sure you give execute permission
> chmod +x your-cron.sh

1. set your cron in crontab

> set your cron in crontab with following command
>
> crontab -e
>
> 0 0 * * * /your/absoulute/path/your-cron.sh >> /your/absoulute/path/logs/your-cron-output.log  2>&1
>
> write command and save it
> use crontab -l to make sure it is saved properly

https://crontab.guru/ is a site that helps you with scheduling cron.

0 0 * * * mean Cron run daily At 00:00.

Comment: Have already written the code to execute at  00:00.
but the issue is that the code will run twice instead of once.
and if I turn of nodejs application in Cpanel, the job will still update my database